# Django+Postgres DB constraint errof

Tags: django, postgresql, unique-constraint

I have 2 models:

```py
class YouTubeCurrentChannelStat(models.Model):
    blogger = models.ForeignKey(
        BloggerProfile,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='youtube_channel_stat'
    )
    channel_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
    blog_theme = models.TextField(max_length=150, blank=True)   
    channel_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    subscribers = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    views = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    videos_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=5000)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField()
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, default='')
```

and:

```py
class YouTubeVideoItemsCurrentStat(models.Model):
    channel = models.ForeignKey(YouTubeCurrentChannelStat, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='videos_data')
    video_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
    stat_data = models.JSONField()  # Updated daily with a Celery Task
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, default='')
```

Second is related to first as FK.
I use create_or_update method of Django ORM.
When i create Postgres DB record for the first time - it creates without any issues.

But when I want to update it I get this error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "socials_youtubecurrentchannelstat_pkey" 
    DETAIL:  Key (channel_id)=(UCd3rBmH-OiF7tp3pye9LJIg) already exists
```

My create task looks like:

```py
def update_videos_db_records(channel_id, response, video_id):
    YouTubeVideoItemsCurrentStat.objects.update_or_create(
        video_id=video_id,
        channel_id=channel_id,
        stat_data=dict(
            title=response.get('title', ''),
            likes=response.get('likes', 0),
            views=response.get('views', 0),
            thumbnail=response.get('thumb_url', ''),
            comments=response.get('comments', 0),
            dislikes=response.get('dislikes', 0),
            favourites=response.get('favourite', 0)
        ),
        last_updated=datetime.datetime.now()
    )
```

Also I tried it this way:

```py
def update_videos_db_records(channel_id, response, video_id):
    YouTubeVideoItemsCurrentStat.objects.filter(
        video_id=video_id,
        channel_id=channel_id).update(
        stat_data=dict(
            title=response.get('title', ''),
            likes=response.get('likes', 0),
            views=response.get('views', 0),
            thumbnail=response.get('thumb_url', ''),
            comments=response.get('comments', 0),
            dislikes=response.get('dislikes', 0),
            favourites=response.get('favourite', 0)
        ),
        last_updated=datetime.datetime.now()
    )
```

But it raised the same error.

Method description on Django docs says:

> Like get_or_create() and create(), if you’re using manually specified primary keys and an object needs to be created but the key already exists in the database, an IntegrityError is raised.

It looks like the root of my problem.
I guess disabling constraint check on DB is not the  best solution
But how should I make it correct?

Answer (score 0):

You've got a `channel` field in your second model, but it doesn't have a `channel_id` field. Try to use `channel__id` or `channel__pk` instead

Comment: it identified in DB as chennel_id. Postfix "id" adds automatically

Comment: So, have you tried it allready?

Comment: Yes. I did. Relations mapped correctly

Comment: Do you mean I'm rigth or not?

Comment: I mean that it was not a case. Finally I figured out that I passed "defaults" as *kwargs and they were not mapped correctly. Anyway I fixed the problem by creating 2 separate methods. One - for create a DB record, Second - for filter and update.
@Dominux, thnx for your time